# Trying to edit order detail page in Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a restaurant website using Woocommerce. Trying to display the linked products in a modal. So I have parent products and linked products(child). When user clicks on cart icon for the parent products, then the linkd/child products appear in a modal. User can then select multiple products from there and add to cart. It works almost perfectly. But I want to display the child products under respective parent product in order detail page(in admin) and in email(invoice). Currently the child products appear twice. As parent products and again under the parent. As you see the green marked products are child. I do not want them to appear again as marked in red.

Here is the front end: https://technovicinity.com/development/wordpress/mahmodul/bbeatery/our-menu/

Thank you all experts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0czTf.png)

here is the code:

```html
<div style="padding-left: 12px;width: 125%;padding-top: 20px;">
   <?php
   global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
   
    $product_id =  $item->get_product_id(); 
            if($product_id ){ 
            $product = new WC_Product($product_id);
            $upsells = $product->get_upsell_ids();
            if(!empty( $upsells )){
            
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'no_found_rows' => 1,
            'posts_per_page' => 30,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'post__in' => $upsells,
            'post__not_in' => array($item_id), 
            );
            
            $product_upsells = new WP_Query($args);
            
            if ($product_upsells->have_posts()) :  
            $i=1;
            while ( $product_upsells->have_posts() ) : $product_upsells->the_post();   

            
   
  
             $child_name = get_the_title();
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE  order_item_name ='$child_name' AND order_id = '$order->id'", OBJECT );
   
    
   foreach($results as $row){
       $order_product_name = $row->order_item_name;  
     
     if($child_name == $order_product_name){ ?>
            
             <li>
   <?php
                 //print_r($post->ID);  
                $child_name = get_the_title(); 
                $_product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
                $Price = $_product->get_price();    
                $currency_number = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); 
                echo $child_name;
     ?>
             <span style="float:right;">    
    <?php  echo $currency_number.$Price. '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    X    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1';   ?> 
             <span style="float:right">
    <?php $total_order =  $Price * 1;   $total_order; ?>             
             </span> 
              <span style="float:right; padding-left:46px;">
    <?php echo $currency_number.''.$total_order; ?>             
             </span>
             
             </li>
            
            <?php   
   /*echo "<br>";
   echo $post->ID;
   echo "<br>"; */ 
   ?>
 
            <?php
     }
   }
    
            $i++;
            endwhile;
            endif; 
            
            wp_reset_postdata(); 
            
            } 
     }
            ?>   
            </div>
```

Comment: can you post a code example?  what does the php look like?  It seems like this could be fixed with a conditional.  If it's shown as a child, don't show it as a parent (or something like that).

Comment: Hi. I have added the code in my original post. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you for helping me.